# Azure ADDS synced to AAD

Tags: active-directory, azure, ldap, entra-id

I have a requirement to implement Active Directory Domain Services with the current Azure AD that is syncing to our on premise AD.
The requirement for ADDS is because we need LDAPS. My question is there a way to implement ADDS in such a way that it would be synced to AAD, not the other way around?

All tutorials that I could find are describing AAD synced to ADDS, while ADDS is used as a primary client domain and not on premise domain controller as it is in my case.

Answer (score 0):

At one point they had a preview feature called **User Writeback**, but that has since been removed. Even then the sync would still be 'towards' Azure and not the other way around

It looks like Group and Device Writeback are actually implemented but I doubt that helps you. Probably would need to go 3rd party if you want true Cloud-to-On-Prem sync.

[Azure AADC Preview Features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-feature-preview#user-writeback)

[Hybrid Tools Comparison](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-tools-comparison)

---

Wow I really missed the ball there...

As far as AADDS back to AAD, it is in the same boat as AAD with not being able to natively sync back to on-prem.

> The NTLM and Kerberos compatible password hashes are always stored in an encrypted manner in Azure AD. These hashes are encrypted such that only **Azure** AD Domain Services has access to the decryption keys.
>
> [...]
>
> there is no synchronization from your managed domain back to your Azure AD tenant

[Azure ADDS Sync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-synchronization#objects-that-are-not-synchronized-to-your-azure-ad-tenant-from-your-managed-domain)

Comment: Is there than a way to maybe sync from on prem AD to ADDS? Maybe configure replication of some sort?

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you saying from on-prem to cloud sync?

Comment: so ADDS is basically there so that you can logon your on premise clients. As I do not have ADDS currently and have only on prem AD controller, which then syncs to Azure AD. I would like to sync my on prem AD controller to ADDS, so for example two connectors one syncing to Azure AD and one to ADDS. The reason for ADDS would be just so that I can make LDAPS work and as an interim solution while I do not decide to shut off on prem AD controller and replace it with ADDS.

Comment: So you're saying you would like to have a separate domain for your users? Usually you would just have one on-prem AD for both local logon and sync to AAD for cloud logon, no need to separate them. If you wanted to I supposed you could create a trust between the two local domains (or forests) and have only one syncing with Azure but I don't a reason to complicate the situation with that.

Comment: No, just the opposite I would like to have the same domain and users on local AD controller, Azure AD and ADDS. The need for ADDS is because I need LDAPS and there is no LDAPS on Azure AD.

Comment: I gotcha now, you're using *Azure* ADDS, not on prem ADDS. See updated answer

Comment: I understand. Is it however possible to sync from on premise to AAD and ADDS at the same time. Maybe by creating two connectors in some way, one from on prem to AAD and omne from on prem to ADDS?